# Magento 2 : Admin : Change order status from pending to complete

Tags: magento-2.1

I have created new order from admin. Now it is in Pending state. I need to print invoice pdf but for this order should be in Completed state. I am not able to figure out the way to make it completed from Admin. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is you created an invoice for your order.

Comment: No. I have just created order. Do I need to create invoice after order creation?

Comment: As mention in below answer, create your Invoice and change your order status to complete. you can able to print your invoice pdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can print invoice your Magento order from admin by follow below steps

```
Admin >> Sales >> Order >> Open Order >> Click Invoice >> Submit Invoice
```

Now you can see your order invoice in "**Invoices**" tab just under "**ORDER VIEW"**.

Click on "**View**" link, you can see you print button for invoice print.

Comment: Thank you. It is working now. I have printed invoice but facing one issue that Rupee symbol and actual value is overlapping (e.g ₹45.00). What will be the reason. Any idea?

Comment: You can add one space after currency symbol form Admin >> Store >> Currency Symbol. Symbol after space will display everywhere.

Comment: I have tried with above solution, actually it is not showing the our Indian currency symbol in pdf. Could you please check my question where I have added pdf screenshot https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182728/magento-2-rupee-currency-symbol-overlapping-on-price?noredirect=1#comment251318_182728

Comment: Once payment is done, the order status showing as "Processing" by default but I wanted to show as "Pending/New" similar to "Cash On Delivery".  If I want to set the order status as "Pending/New" programmatically once the order is placed. What should I do? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Shipment & Invoice to complete your order. Here is order workflow http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/order-workflow.html