# Magento 2 : Rupee (currency) symbol overlapping on price

Tags: magento-2.1

Whenever I print the invoice, Rupee symbol gets overlapped with the price. When I copy this price on the text editor, it shows me correct but in pdf, it is overlapping the price. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and give us more details, what did you do and what is the exact errors (i.e screenshots)

Comment: Added screenshot. Plz have a look

Comment: you are using mata utf-8 ?

Comment: its not overlapping issue. rupees symbol not supported in your current pdf font library.

Comment: @Dhaval What will you suggest then?

Comment: Can you try @ToanNguyen answer . add lib/dejavu-sans/DejaVuSans.ttf font in directory and replace new font name with current font in php file.
Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Will try and let you know

Answer (score 2):

we need to extend `Invoice.php` file.

```
 Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php
```

We can't override `AbstractPdf.php` directly.

I have created one module for this. You can  download from [here](https://github.com/gunjali-agarwal/magento).Its working properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your PDF font to some other fonts which supports your currency symbol. (Such as Dejavu-Sans)

To do so, you will need to add a plugin for AbstractPdf class.

> app/code/Stackoverflow/PdfFont/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf">
        <plugin name="add_font_to_pdf" type="Stackoverflow\PdfFont\Plugin\AddFontToPdf"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Stackoverflow/PdfFont/Plugin/AddFontToPdf.php

```
<?php

namespace Stackoverflow\PdfFont\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class AddFontToPdf
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\ReadInterface
     */
    protected $_rootDirectory;

    /**
     * AddFontToPdf constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
    )
    {
        $this->_rootDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::ROOT);
    }

    public function beforeDrawLineBlocks($subject, $page, array $draw, array $pageSettings = [])
    {
        foreach ($draw as $key => $values) {
            if(isset($values['lines'])) {
                $lines = $values['lines'];
                foreach ($lines as $k => $v) {
                    foreach ($v as $k1 => $v1) {
                        $v[$k1]['font_file'] = $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/dejavu-sans/DejaVuSans.ttf');
                        $lines[$k][$k1] = $v[$k1];
                    }
                }

                $draw[$key]['lines'] = $lines;
            }

        }
        // Update the $draw array to add your font
        return [$page, $draw, $pageSettings];
    }
}
```

However, this way is for drawing item, not for shipping address info. Because the shipping address part used the protected functions to set font style.

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php

```
protected function _setFontRegular()

protected function _setFontBold()

protected function _setFontItalic()
```

You need to override the class in order to override those functions.

```
/**
 * Set font as regular
 *
 * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
 * @param  int $size
 * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
 */
protected function _setFontRegular($object, $size = 7)
{
    $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
        $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/dejavu-sans/DejaVuSans.ttf')
    );
    $object->setFont($font, $size);
    return $font;
}

/**
 * Set font as bold
 *
 * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
 * @param  int $size
 * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
 */
protected function _setFontBold($object, $size = 7)
{
    $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
        $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/dejavu-sans/DejaVuSans.ttf')
    );
    $object->setFont($font, $size);
    return $font;
}

/**
 * Set font as italic
 *
 * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
 * @param  int $size
 * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
 */
protected function _setFontItalic($object, $size = 7)
{
    $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
        $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/dejavu-sans/DejaVuSans.ttf')
    );
    $object->setFont($font, $size);
    return $font;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a [module on github](https://github.com/rossmc/SalesPdfFonts) that replaces the font Magento uses to the [GNU Free Font](https://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/) which has much wider support for different writing systems.